# How can you denote the access modifiers "friend" and "protected friend" in UML?

Tags: c#, uml, vb.net, access-modifiers

The symbols for access modifiers that I know are relevant for many different languages:

> **public**:        +
>   **private**:       -
>   **protected**:  #
>   **package**:    ~ (*or none*)

*However*, in VB.NET there are other such access modifiers -- `friend`, and `protected friend` (*these are called `internal` and `protected internal` in c#*). What are the UML symbols for these access modifiers?

Is `friend` close enough to "package access" that it could be denoted with a tilde "`~`"? Would that then mean that `protected friend` could be denoted as "`#~`"?

Comment: This [question on Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3434034/how-to-show-protected-internal-in-uml) seems to suggest that there isn't a definitive answer in language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [CSU Santa Barbara](http://www.csci.csusb.edu/dick/samples/uml1b.html)'s web site:

> We sometimes need an operation that has full access to a classes
>   private information and yet must not be applied to a single object. In
>   C++, for example, we have "friend functions" and "friend operations".
>   These are indicated by placing the stereotype "<<friend>>" in front of
>   the operation in the UML class diagram.

So you just annotate it and it is understood by other UML users.

Comment: `friend` in C++ is very different from `Friend` in VB.NET.

Comment: @svick That's beside the point. In both cases, there is no symbol defined by the UML language standard to represent that visibility. The approach would be the same.

Comment: Thanks @DDay, based on your answer I think that maybe a combination of both a stereotype and an access modifier might be useful for `protected friend` -- `<<friend>>#`.